# Hide/show tabs depending on when the virtual keyboard is visible

Tags: codenameone

Can anyone help? I'm trying to hide/show my tabs when the virtual keyboard appears/disappears. I can achieve this with the below code depending on if the field has focus or not however if the user presses the hardware back button (to remove the keyboard) this doesn't remove focus from the field and therefore the tabs will not show again. Ideally I would like a way to show and hide depending on the virtual keyboard. Using Netbeans IDE 8.2 codename one plugin version 6.0. Maybe I am going about this the wrong way, any advise would be appreciated.

```
t_TelFind.addFocusListener(new FocusListener()
        {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(final Component t_TelFind)
        {
            DTOTabs.hideTabs();
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(final Component t_TelFind)
        {
            DTOTabs.showTabs();
        }
    });

         t_TelDelete.addFocusListener(new FocusListener()
        {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(final Component t_TelDelete)
        {
            DTOTabs.hideTabs();
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(final Component t_TelDelete)
        {
            DTOTabs.showTabs();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detecting virtual keyboards is really hard even in native. We have some code that does that and exposed that as an API in `Display` specifically as `addVirtualKeyboardListener`. Even that method specifically declares that the API might fail for some cases.

I suggest using smaller tabs or using creative ways such as the whatsapp approach of folding the tabs as you scroll down.

Comment: Thanks for the support Shai. I persisted a little with focusGained and focusLost, adding in a done listener then setting focus elsewhere. Unfortunately the field won't lose focus even once the done button is pressed. Not the best solution. I have worked around my issue for now by making the container scrollable so my field is no longer obstructed. WhatsApp approach could be useful in the future so thanks!